Character Sliding up hill when he is not supposed too UE5

I am basicly calculating weather the floor is up or down and when is down it should give the player speed but when ever a floor is at an angle even when im facing it so i would be going up hill it thinks im going down hill
here is how im getting the floor normal instance

